# what do these directory is used for in linux? etc/ bin/ and lib/

Tags: linux

Guys what do these libraries used for in linux?

```
/etc/
/lib/
/bin/
```

care to explain each?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: Hardly your cat's fault that your question is off-topic and has an easily googled answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name says:

- etc -> To keep configuration files
- lib -> To keep libraries that can be used by installed software or other softwares in your system.
- bin -> Binary files

Comment: hi @shadyabhi, do you happen to know `/var/log/messages` this folder too? what is it used for? im trying to find it in my system, it cant be found

Comment: `/var/log/messages` That will be a file & it may exist or it may not depending on how syslogging is configured on your system. I can't say anything about why it isn't present without getting your configuration file for your syslogging program.

Comment: so what is it used for? what kind of messages stored in there if ever there is?

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated `/var/log/` is a directory generally used for storing logs. All programs generally write to `/dev/log` file socket which is picked up by syslog program such as syslog-ng or rsyslog etc etc. Then this syslog program reads from that file socket and depending on which program is sending logs, write to a appropriate file under `/var/log/` generally. Generally, `messages` is present and programs write to it most. You can check what are your recent files in `/var/log` by using `ls -ltr /var/log`. It could be everything.log or messages.log etc etc.

Comment: bin - Contains binary files to configure the operating system.(In the binary format)_________ etc - contains machine specific configuration files in editable format. _________ lib -> contains shared binary files which are shared by bin and sbin.

Answer (score 6):

You can read all about the details by looking up the [filesystem hierarchy standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), but in a nutshell:

- `/etc`: Configuration information
- `/lib`: Libraries
- `/bin`: Program binaries that are important to the functioning of the system. (Non-essential binaries are generally found in `/usr/bin`; these are generally installed with the operating system distribution. Programs installed after OS installation are generally stored in `/usr/local/bin`.)